# Mudar a cor da linha do RecycleView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

tenho um `RecycleView` e gostaria de mudar a cor da linha quando selecionado, o clique da seleção eu já tenho implementado e funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

No `Adapter` da sua `RecycleView` crie uma variável para controlar a posição que esta selecionada na lista e defina inicialmente o valor -1.

No `onBindViewHolder` defina o `onClicklistner` para atualização da posição na variável e chamar o `notifyDataSetChanged`.
Ainda no `onBindViewHolder` também coloquei o `if` para verificar a posição da variável com a posição do item sendo atualizado e mudar as cores.

Com a chamado do notifyDataSetchangeg() o `onBindViewHolder` é reexecutado, com isso passara novamente pelo `if` para decisão da cor do itens, trocando a cor do item já selecionado anteriormente e do item selecioado atualmente.

Exemplo:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {    
    holder.row_linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            row_index=position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    if(row_index==position){
        holder.row_linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.row_linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Coloquei pra mudar a cor do TextView, mudou a cor blz, mas o click em cima do texto não funciona, depois dele o click está ok.

Comment: Não entendi, poderia explicar melhor ?

Comment: Na minha CardView tenho apenas um TextView, no meu adapter tenho pego o click que retorna a posição do Recycle. O que v mostrou funcionou, mas quando muda de cor não consigo mais receber a posição do Recycle, Entendeu?

Comment: Desculpe, não consegui entender ainda, adicione na sua pergunta o seu código e o que esta acontecendo, mais detalhadamente...